# Xubuntu 20.04 default file system is ext2/ext3 and not ext4?

Tags: xubuntu, filesystem, ext4

I installed Xubuntu 20.04 on a 2T SSD drive. To my surprise, it installed the old ext2/ext3 file system instead of ext4. Why is that?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

and checking file system showed ext2/ext3:

```
$ stat -f -c %T /
ext2/ext3
```

Why did it not install ext4, since Xubuntu is based on Ubuntu and Ubuntu 20.04 uses ext4?

Answer (score 7):

The default filesystem is not `ext2/ext3`, it is `ext4`.

`stat -f` shows the type of a filesystem, so it outputs `ext2/ext3` for `ext4` as well.

You can check what filesystem is by e.g.

```
sudo parted -l
```

or

```
df -T /
```

Comment: Marvelous ! Thank you !